# Comparing array results and then unhiding audio elements

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to compare the the results of 2 arrays, and then make the corresponding elements visible.

I am passing in a list from the controller, and setting the element Id's and Names using the values from the model. I can get the values from the ticked check boxes and these alert correctly, but when I try and get the values from the appropriate audio tags, I get undefined.

```
<div style="display:none;" name="audioDiv" id="audioDiv">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
         <div class="divclass" value="@item.Name" id="audioDiv" hidden>
            <h1> @item.Track - @item.Singer</h1>
            <audio controls id="audioPlayer" value="@item.Name">
                <source src="~/MP3s/@item.Name" type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
         </div>

    }
</div>

    function myFunction() {
        document.querySelector(".table").style.display = "none";
        var audionodes = document.getElementsByTagName('audio').value;
        alert(audionodes)
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('playlist');

        var vals = "";
        for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                vals += "," + checkboxes[i].value;
            }
        }
        if (vals) vals = vals.substring(1);
        alert(vals);
        alert(audionodes)      



    }
```

I want to be able to compare the values of 'vals' and 'audionodes' and then un hide the corresponding audio elements. so for example - if the checkbox for luis fonzi - despacito is ticked, on the click of submit, I want that audio element to be visible, and the table I had displaying the 'playlist' information to be hidden.

One array will have the values of the checked boxes - so a list of track names. The second will contain all of the values for every hidden audio element - which is a value for every song. Once they've been compared, it then makes the appropriate audio elements visible.

Comment: in order to do that you need to tell use what your 2 array has

Comment: it has string values in each, so - the first array will contain a list of file names for the songs, depending on if the box is checked. The next array will should contain a list of all the string values for all the songs to compare against. This will then unhide the appropriate audio elements which have been automatically set as hidden.

Comment: Please edit your question and try to create snippet

Comment: added array information!

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand you right, you are trying to display the audios based on the checkbox selection, in order to do that you need to check 2 arrays and display them, I converted html collection to array and iterated over them, you can check my comments and implement it in your own.

```js
document.querySelector(".table").style.display = "none";
//getting all audio controls with element and its value
var audionodes = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')).map(a => {
  return {
    element: a,
    value: a.getAttribute("value")
  }
});

//getting all the checkboxes checked
var checkboxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).reduce((prev, next) => {
  if (next.checked) {
    prev.push(next.getAttribute("value"))
  }
  return prev;
}, []);

//filtering the audio control values with checkboxes and displaying them.
audionodes.filter(a => checkboxes.indexOf(a.value) >= 0).forEach(a => {
  a.element.style.display = "block";

});
```

```css
audio {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <audio value="luis fonzi - despacito">test</audio>
</table>
<input value="luis fonzi - despacito" name="playlist" checked type="checkbox">
<input value="luis fonzi - despacit1o" name="playlist1" type="checkbox">
```